# android how to maintain session

Tags: php, android, web-services, session-cookies

I am building a login application in android in which i am hitting a url(with username and password) upto that part it works fine but after that whenever I am hitting a url(once the user is authenticated) , it return nothing(i.e. a error message like please login first).

I got somewhere that it is the error of phpSessionId(i.e. the session is destroyed for further request) and If we want our Android application to stay authenticated on the server side we need to fetch that id after the first connection and then send it in the headers of all our subsequent requests.

But the problem is that I am unable to get the sessionId from header of the first connection and sending it with further request along with the header.

Please give me some codes or links to complete the task properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue of session handling in Android. Android cant handle the session itself(which a simple browser can) so we have to handle it explicitly. I changed the code for http connection a bit. Created an instance of DefaultHttpClient in the first Activity when connection established

```
public static DefaultHttpClient httpClient;
```

For the first time connection,I did the following:

public class ServiceHandler {

```
static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

public ServiceHandler() {

}

public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
    return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
}

public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {

        // http client

        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            httpResponse = MainActivity.httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = MainActivity.httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;

}
```

}

and call as following way

```
jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
```

this will help me too to solve session issue in Android.